# How to refresh the main page after the <form> opens a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, page-refresh

I have a form that opens a new window with the results.
Why? Because the new page calcalates the data and produces a PDF on screen.
So in simple form the code (lets say index.php) looks like this:

```
<?
//loads data and finds the next availiable numerical (autoincrease) ID. e.g. $nextid=103;
?>
<form action=newpage.php method=post target=_blank>
Next Availiable ID: <input type=text name=id value="<?=$nextid?>"><br/>
Your Name: input type=text name=thename maxlength=64><br/>
<button type=submit>Go!</submit>
<form>
```

After submitting the form, the newpage.php opens in a new window and produces the pdf. When I return to index.php (the page with the form) I would like it to be refreshed so it will get a new availiable id number.

I've tried javascript functions on the button object (onmouseup, onsubmit etc) but loading a page doesn't work. To test the code I typed an alert ("test"); command and it runs! When it comes to loading a page or refreshin the current page, it wont work.

onclick="loadUrl('http://somesite.com')" doesn't work either.

Right now I'm bypassing it with control code in the newpage.php, yet I would like the page to be refreshed in order PHP to read the database.
Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
<form action="newpage.php" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="javascript: setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 1000);return true;">
  Next Availiable ID: <input type="text" name="id" value="<?= $nextid ?>"><br/>
  Your Name: <input type="text" name="thename" maxlength="64"><br/>
  <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this inside the form tag :

```
onsubmit = "document.location = 'http://somewebsite.com'"
```